# two list find values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

should look something like this:

```
if items in both lists (equal/ larger/smaller):
   do something
else:
   if items in both lists (equal/ larger/smaller):
       do something
   else:
       do something
```

Comment: Your earlier example is basically a loop where you set n to increase, so why not use the for loop? In any case, if you really want to use the while loop then you need to identify clearly when your while loop ends instead of the for loop which ends after iterating through every element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's unclear but seems like this is what you want:

```
list3 = [i for i in list2 if i not in list1]
```

Now:

```
print(list3)
```

Is:

```
[4]
```

If one element list, you care about, do:

```
print(next(iter(list3),list3))
```

Then output:

```
4
```

And if `list3` is a list of more than 1 element for example:

```
[1,2]
```

This will still output:

```
[1,2]
```

Or `^` operator for sets (second part for slicing out first half of the list):

```
list3 = list(set(list2)^set(list1))
list3=list3[len(list3)//2:]
```

Now:

```
print(list3)
```

Is:

```
[4]
```

Then also can use `next` stuff for `list3`

Or can do `symmetric_difference`:

```
list3 = set.symmetric_difference(set(list1),set(list2))
list3=list(list3)[len(list3)//2:]
```

Now:

```
print(list3)
```

Is:

```
[4]
```

Can do same stuff for `next`

**And as you want a while loop:**

```
l=[i for i in list2 if i not in list1]
it=iter(l)
while l!=list3:
   list3.append(next(it))
```

*A dummy way of doing this tho ...*

And now:

```
print(list3)
```

Is:

```
[4]
```

And can do same `next` stuff

Or even better:

```
num = 0
while num < len(list2):
    if list2[num] != list1[num]:
        list3.append(list2[num])
    num += 1
```

And now:

```
print(list3)
```

Is:

```
[4]
```

And can do same `next` stuff

Comment: Did you answer this on your phone 

Comment: @vash_the_stampede No??, why you're asking that?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I never answer questions not on computer

Comment: @D.James Edited mine

Comment: @D.James Editeded again, gotcha hpe well

Comment: Just because the emojis and your Uber skills haha I’m on my phone maybe they translated, you n blushing jpp and you know the regs give me the most competetion

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Pk i don't fully understand :-), (i still can do emojis on computer tho 

Comment: I’m going through solve one via iPhone watch me go

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Did you do that yet, i don'e see it? :-)x